# Transaction Vs Stored procedure

Tags: database, stored-procedures, transactions, foreign-keys, rdbms

Multivalued Attributes are a common scenario is any database-oriented application. One of the common use cases is to add a new entity which goes to both of the tables and connected by their foreign key.

For example, a new employee added to a system on the first day of his/her job where she/he start working under a certain team in the company. This person's record is saved in two tables, one table store the personal info (`employee`) of the employee while other tables (`employee_team`) stores the duration of an employee with each team in their entire time in the company. The employee management system has one long form for a new employee (it is just an example to represent the use case) that takes all of this employee information including the department where this person starts working with. To save this information insertion in two tables obvious, which are related using foreign key attribute.

One of the ways to implement such a scenario is to use `Begin Transaction` and `Commit` and make 2 insert queries in between from the application. The other solution could create a parameterized stored procedure and make a single call to that procedure from the application.

From a database point of view, both solution probably results in the same activities in the database server. However, is it fair to say that, from the application's point of view, the former solution may take more time for communicating twice than the later solution? What are the pros and cons of each of the procedure? What are the benefits of using one over other, both from the database point of view and application point of view?

My current system is based on `PHP` and `MySql`, but I guess, this scenario is common to all types of RDBMS.

Answer (score 3):

You make it sound like transactions and stored procedures are two different approaches to the same problem. They are not. To ensure data consistency between two participating tables, you would still need to use a transaction in the stored procedure.

Now, it's clear that if you emit separate statements in the client for, say, `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, `SELECT...`, `INSERT...`, `COMMIT`, then that results in more messages going back and forth than if you issue the whole thing as one compound SQL statement, but network communication is rarely the bottleneck in database performance anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I actually did not mean to sound like these two are two things :P. I like the second part of your answer. However, considering the microservice architecture application, and a high volume of transactions, is there any other pros and cons of using one or another other than network communication?

Answer (score 0):

If your application sends a single **query** i.e.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

--INSERT 1

--INSERT 2

END TRANSACTION
```

Then it is still one call to the database, it just happens to be doing two things, and is basically equivalent (ignoring specifics about query plans etc.) as calling a single stored procedure...

Edit:: As I said it depends on the product you use, but for example in Microsoft SQL Server you can do

```
INSERT INTO [Table] ([Name]) VALUES ('Bob');  
INSERT INTO [Table2] ([Table1Id]) VALUES (SCOPE_IDENTITY());
```

Comment: Do you think this is possible to create a query like this when I need the last insert id from the first query and insert that to the second?

Comment: Yes... that is certainly possible... it depends on the database product you use but they all have functions that will get the last inserted id, like SCOPE_IDENTITY etc.

Comment: Can you give me some example standard SQL statements for this?